# Динамическое добавление прямоугольников Swing(Java)

Tags: java, swing

Нужно реализовать добавление прямоугольников (во всю ширину окна) с цветами радуги. Когда последняя полоса отрисовуетя цикл начинается сначала.
Не пойму как рисовать прямоугольники, чтобы при открытии окна прямоугольники появлялись с определенной задержкой.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    Window() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        //стандартное определение размера окна и его положения на экране в зависимости от расширения экрана
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension dimension = toolkit.getScreenSize();
        setBounds(dimension.width / 2 - 250, dimension.height / 2 - 100, 350, 200);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            Color[] colorList = {Color.RED, Color.ORANGE, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN, Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA};

            public int heightResRect = Window.this.getHeight() / 7;
            public int widthRect = Window.this.getWidth();

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponents(g);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                //((Graphics2D) g).setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC));
                for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 7; i += heightResRect, j++) {
                    g.drawRect(0, i, widthRect, heightResRect);
                    g.setColor(colorList[j]);
                    g.fillRect(0, i, widthRect, heightResRect);
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        };
        setTitle("My Rainbow");
        this.getContentPane().add(panel);
    }
}
```

Я так понимаю отрисовка должна быть в цикле, но как сделать динамическую отрисовку в реальном времени не понимаю.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо учитывать время при перерисовках:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Window();
    }
    Window() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        //стандартное определение размера окна и его положения на экране в зависимости от расширения экрана
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension dimension = toolkit.getScreenSize();
        setBounds(dimension.width / 2 - 250, dimension.height / 2 - 100, 350, 200);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            Color[] colorList = {Color.RED, Color.ORANGE, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN, Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA};

            public int heightResRect = (Window.this.getHeight()-35) / 7;
            public int widthRect = Window.this.getWidth();

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponents(g);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                g.clearRect(0, 0, Window.this.getWidth(), Window.this.getHeight());
                //((Graphics2D) g).setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC));
                for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < 7; i += heightResRect, j++) {
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() % 700< j * 100)
                        return;
                    g.drawRect(0, i, widthRect, heightResRect);
                    g.setColor(colorList[j]);
                    g.fillRect(0, i, widthRect, heightResRect);
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        };
        setTitle("My Rainbow");
        this.getContentPane().add(panel);

        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                panel.repaint();
            }
        },0 ,40, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй **Timer** для вызова метода *repaint*,  что является **Thread safe** и не блокирует EDT, что позволяет безопасно обновлять твою JPanel.

```
Color[] colors = new Color[3]; // три цвета , так для примера 
int index = 0; // для перемещения по массиву цветов
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
 super.paintComponent(g);
 g.setColor(colors[index]);
 g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight()); //getWidth и getHeight при условии что класс наследует JPanel
}
```

Далее в конструкторе :

```
public YourClass() {
 color[0] = Color.BLUE;
 color[0] = Color.RED;
 color[0] = Color.YELLOW;
 Timer timer = new Timer(1000, e-> {
  repaint();
  index++;
  if(index == 3)
   index = 0;
 });
 timer.start
}
//ну а дальше код который я упустил :) удачи
```